# Mulitple Indexes for the same label In Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

```
is there any problem with multiple index for same label
```

i just created a label with PERSON and created a index with gender property
like

```
CREATE INDEX on :PERSON(gender);
```

next i created another index for the same label with first_name property

```
CREATE INDEX on :PERSON(first_name);
```

is there any problem, i feel that iam getting performance issue when i used the same label before and after adding second index.

Comment: You can do this. What's the issue?

Comment: before when i add the second index.. when i run a query on 2 Lakhs nodes it takes 5 mins of time, after the seconds index it takes above 10 mins, i feel this might be the issue..